# Android: unusual log output (RBS)

Tags: android, logcat

I just set up some logging with `adb logcat` to generate a log overnight. The idea was to capture and investigate a periodic (roughly daily) crash in my Android phone. However, as I set it up, I found the below repeated log entry and did not find any results with Google as to what it might be (in fact, I did not manage to find any reference to it). The goal of this question is to learn about the log entries (not about debugging the crash in my phone, though obviously if the two are related that would be greatly appreciated). The log repeatedly contains a `check_cancelable` and `check_need_pause`. That repeats very often (every few dozen milliseconds) and looks like this:

```
08-06 23:21:39.197  1327  1747 D RBS     : [captain.c] [check_cancelable:444] egistest g_need_cancel = 0 
08-06 23:21:39.198  1327  1747 D RBS     : [captain.c] [check_need_pause:450] egistest g_need_pause = 0 
08-06 23:21:39.198  1327  1747 D RBS     : [captain.c] [check_cancelable:444] egistest g_need_cancel = 0 
08-06 23:21:39.198  1327  1747 D RBS     : [captain.c] [check_need_pause:450] egistest g_need_pause = 0 
08-06 23:21:39.228  1327  1747 D RBS     : [captain.c] [check_cancelable:444] egistest g_need_cancel = 0 
08-06 23:21:39.228  1327  1747 D RBS     : [captain.c] [check_need_pause:450] egistest g_need_pause = 0 
08-06 23:21:39.228  1327  1747 D RBS     : [captain.c] [check_cancelable:444] egistest g_need_cancel = 0 
08-06 23:21:39.228  1327  1747 D RBS     : [captain.c] [check_need_pause:450] egistest g_need_pause = 0
```

I can't believe that no-one has noticed this before, so probably I missed something, but what exactly is RBS and why does it seem to flood the android syslog?

System details:
OnePlus Nord N10 5G (up-to-date, stock OxygenOS, meaning Android 11 with patch level June 2021).
I created the log using freshly downloaded adb commandline tools (from a Windows 10 machine).